# How to get total sum of array

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to add together the contents of an array (integers).
for example:

```
var myArray;
var answer;
myArray[0]=2;
myArray[1]=5;
answer=myArray[0]+myArray[1];
```

answer should equal 7.Could you help me, please? Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you should probably read an introductory book on programming. It will be much more useful in the long run.

Comment: yeah, also, what problem are you encountering?

Comment: Also, ANY time a script doesn't work, you should first look in the error console to see what script errors are being reported.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array

```
var myArray = [];
```

As you get more values into your array you might consider a loop, example:

```
var myArray = [];
var answer = 0;
myArray[0]=2;
myArray[1]=5;

for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
{ 
   answer += myArray[i];
}

console.log(answer);
```

Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: This is smashing. I understand now. but i'm getting the answer to equal "NaN". Any ideas why?

Comment: @Matthias +1 Actually I didn't know that, but overall I find what is on w3cSchool to be of good quality (Not as good as SO of course :) ). The link was just meant to be an example of a for loop.

Comment: @user1910834 Not really no - are you using the exact code? I just checked in my browser. It logs 7.

Comment: Ah, I found out that "NaN" stands for "Not a number" :P i'll sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get an error.

you need to intialize your variable `myArray` to be an array.

`var myArray = [];`

After I do that,  `answer` has the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `myArray` as an array, otherwise `myArray[0]` means a property named `0` on `undefined` (which will probably blow up) rather than an index access.

```
var myArray = [];
...
```